# Restauração de Backup Postgree

Tags: postgresql

Quando restauro um backup no "pgadmin" do Postgree, caso as tabelas do banco contenham registros, dá erro.

Existe alguma possibilidade de eu criar um backup e no momento da restauração, eu informar que quero apagar os dados das tabelas e restaurar?

Pode ser por script SQL mesmo.

Comment: Para realizar o restore em postgres, o indicado é que a base seja dropada, criada uma nova zerada e restaurado o backup então sobre ela.
Caso não seja feito dessa forma, pode ocorrer duplicação de dados

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Fernando. O Problema, é que na minha empresa, os consultores instalam nos clientes a base padrão contendo os registros necessários para o funcionamento do sistema. Quando migramos os dados e pedimos a eles para fazer a instalação, algumas tabelas já contém os dados, aí seria necessário deletar os registros anteriores e gravar os dados da migração.